# comparing values from one row to all other rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compare a certain columns values from a single row against all other rows using pandas. i created the following loop but its taking forever to execute since my dataframe contain abt 400,000 row 
is there a smarter/ faster way to execute this 
sorry i'm not very python fluent im more used to coding in .NET languages

my dataframe looks something like that :

```
    NAME            PROFILE URL             Final Addres
0   ProfileA    appexample.co/userxyz       http://example.com
1   ProfileB    appexample.co/userxyz_1     http://example.com  
2   ProfileC    appexample.co/userabc       http://anotherexample.com
3   ProfileD    appexample.co/userabc_3     http://anotherexample.com
4   ProfileE    appexample.co/userjyl       http://example123.com
```

I am trying to identify duplicate (profiles) in this case (ProfileA  & ProfileB) & (ProfileC & ProfileD) are duplicates because :
1. have the same profile url (eg. user is in user & user_1)
2. have the same Final Address

the current code im using :

```
possible_dup = []
    for row in test.iterrows():
    first = str(row[1]['PROFILE URL'])
    first_url = str(row[1]['Final Address'])
    for sec_row in test.iterrows():
        second = str(sec_row[1]['PROFILE URL'])
        second_url = str(sec_row[1]['Final Address'])
        if (row[1]['PROFILE URL'] == sec_row[1]['PROFILE URL']) :
            continue
        if ((first in second) and (first_url == second_url)):
            dup = '{} , {}'.format(first,second)
            possible_dup.append(dup)
```

the running time exceeded 24 hours and was still running , im using jupyter notebook

Comment: Can you explain a bit more which logic you want to apply. Also it;s best practice to include an expected output based on your example dataframe you've shown on top.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [duplicated()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) method. From the docs:

> Return boolean Series denoting duplicate rows.

Especially useful for you is the optional parameter to select only a subset of columns. Depending on what exactly your goal is, you can do several things with the `duplicated()` method:

To identify rows which are duplicated you'd use

```
duplicates = test.duplicated(subset = ['PROFILE URL', 'FINAL Addres'], keep = False)
```

To identify all users which are duplicate you'd use

```
    duplicate_users = test[test.duplicated(subset = ['PROFILE URL', 'FINAL Addres'], keep = First)]
```

To return a dataframe without duplicates (each former duplicate now present only once):

```
duplicates = test.duplicated(subset = ['PROFILE URL', 'FINAL Addres'])
duplicate_free_df = test.loc[~duplicates]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `duplicated()` with the `keep` argument as False which allows us to identify all the duplicates.

```
df2 = df[df.duplicated(subset=['Final Addres'],keep=False)]

print(df2)


       NAME              PROFILE URL               Final Addres
0  ProfileA    appexample.co/userxyz         http://example.com
1  ProfileB  appexample.co/userxyz_1         http://example.com
2  ProfileC    appexample.co/userabc  http://anotherexample.com
3  ProfileD  appexample.co/userabc_3  http://anotherexample.com
```

Comment: Thanks alot this was very simple and helpful !

Comment: @pshl_slq22447 no problem, if this answered your question don't forget to green tick it (next to the number and up and down arrows) so this question can be closed. did the code run relatively quick on your data set?